Unable to connect Google Analytics data to Power BI
I am unable to connect my Google Analytics data with Power Bi desktop. I pick the connector, add my google login details and I can see the Account and Property but I am unable to see the data tables and am therefore unable to connect to view / chart the GA data. I have administrator role in the company I am trying to connect. This company also connects for getting GA to Firebase.
Is there something I am doing wrong? I have the latest 64bit version of Power Bi desktop.
Thanks in advance
I have tried another company I have access too and got tables.

Based on this old thread :
First, ensure that Power BI Desktop is the latest version.
Then try to clear the previous credentials and reconnect.
Steps about clearing credentials:
1.In Power BI Desktop, Go to the File menu and select Options and Settings > Data Source settings

2.Clear the credential.

The steps about connecting Google Analytics:

In Power BI Desktop, click “Get Data” from the Home ribbon tab.
Select “Online Services” from the categories in the left pane.
Select Google Analytics from the list of online services.
At the bottom of the window, click “Connect.”
You’ll be prompted with a dialog that explains that the Google Analytics connector is a third-party service. Click “Continue” to move forward.
You’ll be prompted to sign in to Google Analytics. When you enter your credentials, you’ll see a message that Power BI would like to have online access. To let Power BI Desktop access your GA data, you’ll want to accept.
After you accept, Power BI Desktop will show that you’re signed in to Google Analytics.
Select “Connect” to link your Google Analytics data with Power BI Desktop.


Thanks, I got it and am now able to get the data.

If my answer helped you don't forget to validate it
